# is it possible to connect two portlets in liferay?

Tags: github, liferay, liferay-6, portlet, jira-plugin

I dont know if I´m right in this community.
Actually I´m trying to evaluate the possibilities of `Liferay`.
In the project I want to show many sources (like `Jira`, `GitHub`, `NAS`) in one Page in a dashboard.
My question is, is it possible to connect the `portlets`?

- For example if I´m clicking on an `Jira`-Task I want to see all Commits from `GitHub`.
- I want to have an "search-portlet" where I can search for People. The Result of the search should show me the `GitHub`-commits, `Jira`-Tasks,.. for this user.

I dont have much experience with `Liferay`, so has anybody ideas if this is possible and maybe could give me some starting advices?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, You can !!**

From my experience, **liferay** will be best option for you.

### Liferay Portal

A portal is generally defined as a software platform for building websites and web applications. Modern portals have added multiple features that make them the best choice for a wide array of web applications and you will be able to ***communicate between portlet*** very easily. [Liferay Portal overview](http://www.liferay.com/products/liferay-portal/overview)

### Portlet

It is liferay plugin project type (I like to call independent project). In your case it may be dashboard containing sources of jira, and more. You should create **search portlet**, where you can implement all logics needed.[Liferay portlet](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/About+Portlets)

Another Term you should understand is:

### Inter-portlet communication

Where getting user information for all portlets, you should implement inter-portlet communication mechanism. There are various ways to do that, I suggest you to go through this link once:[Lifray Inter-portlet communication](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Inter-portlet+communication) [Inter portlet communication](https://portlet-container.java.net/docs/ipc/IPC.html#Samples)

So, go through [Blog](http://www.liferay.com/community/blogs/highlighted), and fell free to ask.

Hope, It will work.

Thanks.